# Windows 10 boot disk is write-protected and bitlocked, will not boot

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I've got a laptop ( Windows 10.0.19041.1) that has bitlocker enabled. When I input my bitlocker key and then attempt to boot, it gives me a flat blue screen for a long time and then turns off.

So I boot into WinRE and get to work. First off, we can see that bitlocker successfully unlocks:

```
X:\windows\system32>manage-bde -status c:
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.19041
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Volume C:[]
[Data Volume]

    Size:                 476.33 GB
    BitLocker Version:    2.0
    Conversion Status:    Used Space Only Encrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 100.0%
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
    Protection Status:    Protection On
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: Unknown
    Automatic Unlock:     Disabled
    Key Protectors:
         TPM
         Numerical Password
```

Something interesting happens when I try to remove bitlocker:

```
X:\windows\system32>manage-bde -off c:
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.19041
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

ERROR: An error occurred (code 0x80070013):
The media is write protected
```

Ok, I know how to fix that, I'll just go into diskpart and

```
X:\windows\system32>diskpart
DISKPART> list disk

Disk ###  Status  Size   Free   Dyn Gpt
--------  ------  ------ ------ --- ---
Disk 0    Online  476 GB 1024KB      *

DISKPART>select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk

DISKPART> attributes disk
Current Read-only State : Yes
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

DISKPART> attributes disk clear readonly

DiskPart failed to clear disk attributes
```

Nope. However the disk is writelocked, it's not something diskpart can fix. The 1024kb free part is interesting, but I figure that's got to be diskpart not playing well with bitlocker or something.

DISM, SFC, and CHKDSK are all unhelpful, as none of them can squeeze past that readonly attribute. I popped into the registry to see if something was up there, but there's no writeprotected key stopping me.

Using windows' built-in "Startup Repair" feature in WinRE fails too. I'm not sure how, the utility  gives rather unhelpful error messages.

Jumping into `C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs` gives us some more interesting data: Despite attempting to boot ~3x today, not a single .evtx file has a changed date newer than 5/16/2021, when the computer was last used.

Current working theory: Somehow windows is unable to remove write protection on the drive at boot, so it's failing to boot. The fact that `winevt\Logs` is old seems to support this theory, as well as how chkdsk and diskpart can't do anything. I see no external flippyswitch on the laptop that would indicate a manual solution to such a problem.

At this point my best guess on next steps would be to `cd` into the C:\ drive and `robocopy` all the user data onto an external hard drive, then format and reinstall. Any recommendations on other courses of action to try?

Comment: Sounds like a firmware issue. maybe data recovery lab can unlock using PC3000.

Comment: If it's an SSD, one indication of drive failure is becoming read-only (in an attempt to prevent further damage). See https://www.partitionwizard.com/resizepartition/ssd-is-read-only.html for some ideas.

Comment: Yeah, it's an nvme ssd. I'm noticing a lot of filesystem damage, so it's probable that the drive is simply failing and needs to be extracted and replaced. Is it on-topic here to ask about resources for data recovery in a new question?

Comment: As mentioned, SSDs will switch to read-only when there is a failure or their life is exhausted. Recover the data from the RE command prompt and replace. One option is to clone the disk (sector by sector) to a new drive then attempt recovery on the new drive. It may work fine and not need any additional work after the clone. But if they are different sizes the partition will need to be expanded and maybe a chkdsk for good measure.